# Where Does Jasper Reports Store Generated Reports

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ant

I've been able to generate sample reports in Jasper Reports tied with ANT and JDK, my question is, when I do the "ant pdf" command, it builds the report successfully, but where does it store it to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strace -f ant pdf` to see which files are being created. You can limit the output of strace to the file-create operations.